# JMeter Proxy Settings for dynamic web pages

Tags: jmeter

I am using JBoss application server which is running on localhost at specific port(8443) and like to test the web pages using Jmeter proxy settings but I wasn't able to record the web pages.

In HTTP Request Defaults, I mentioned the servername as localhost and port as 8443.

Is there any way to record my web application?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the Jmeter guide?

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf